# C++ - Unresolved External Error

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I am currently writing a stack class that uses linked lists. I feel like i am done but I keep getting an Unresolved external error.

Here it is:

```
Error: Unresolved external 'Stack<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Node::Node(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' referenced from C:\USERS\JOHNNY\DESKTOP\STACK\INFIX_TO_RPN.OBJ
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do? I sure don't. I can provide code if necessary.

Comment: Post some code.  I take it Node is a nested class?

Comment: Did you define the template in a header, or a source file?

Comment: node is a nested class. And I defined the template in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's complaining that a function `Stack<...>::Node::Node(std::string)` does not seem to have an implementation. Most likely it's that you've added the declaration for that constructor and used it somewhere, but your implementation is missing or misnamed.

Comment: Or, as we are dealing with templates, the implementation is in another source file, which does not use it.